# What can cause connection timeouts from Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: azure, timeout, cloud

We have a WebApi in Azure that sends requests to a VM cluster that is load balanced via an Azure Cloud Service. We see occasional timeouts where requests are working, then one times out for no reason.  Reissuing the request immediately succeeds.

In Fiddler I see:

[Fiddler] The connection to '[myApp].cloudapp.net' failed. 
Error: TimedOut (0x274c). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.122.42.33:9200
I can't find any telemetry in the portal that shows any kind of error, and all is fine when the request is issued from my api.  Also, I don't see anything in the Event Logs on my VMs.

I am thinking it might have something to do with TCP port closure, but I am unfamiliar with this.  My requests are specifying 'Connection: keep-alive', so I assume that subsequent requests to the same protocol/domain would attempt to use the same connection. It usually works, however.

Is there any kind of throttling on the number of active connections that can come into my Cloud Service?  It is possible that these timeouts happen during peak load (though we don't have enough consistent traffic to verify this).

thanks!

Comment: I also see this behavoir. Which instance size are you using? A0?